# Latex Chapter and section formatting

Tags: formatting

My returned thesis has several formatting corrections notated.  I am a fairly inexperienced in LaTeX, and can only use its basic functionality.  I am having issues with formatting the chapter and section headings.  I tried reading through the package details for titlesec, and have become flustered by the documentation.  I cannot seem to figure out the structure or the commands.  Below is the code I found, and modified for the chapter headings, but I am unsure of it.

```
     \usepackage{titlesec}
     \titleformat{\chapter}[display] 
     {\doublespacing\rmfamily\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}}
     {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\filcenter}{12pt}{\centering\uppercase}
     {\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\filcenter}
```

These are the corrections I am supposed to make:

```
     revise format for first page of each chapter:
     --use uniform double line spacing
     --use 12 point font size for chapter number and chapter title
     --use all caps for the word CHAPTER and for all words in chapter title
     --do not use bold font

      Revise all first level subheads:
      --centered on a line by itself
      --use 12 point font
      --use headline style caps
      --use underline
      --no extra blank space above or below subhead (spacing should match 
        spacing between lines of text)
      --do not use bold font
```

Any help you could offer would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Terry

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful to post a small compilable document with the formatting attempt you've made rather than just a fragment. What document class are you using? Are your chapter headings also supposed to be centred?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is enough to get you started. It's not clear from your description whether the sections are numbered or not. If they aren't remove the `\thesection\hspace*{ 1em}` from the section definition.  It's also not clear what the spacing is supposed to be before sections and after chapters, so you would need to add appropriate `\titlespacing` commands for those.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{setspace}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
     {\doublespacing\normalfont\fillast}
     {\MakeTextUppercase\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
     {0pt}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\scshape\fillast}
  {\uline{\thesection\hspace*{ 1em}#1}}
  {0pt}
  {}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a chapter that has a really really really long title to show how it will wrap and give you double spacing.}

This is the text that follows the chapter. 

\section{This is a section}
This is the text that follows the section.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: The chapter title is not all caps.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for noticing that. I think I subconsciously suppressed that part for aesthetic reasons. :)

Comment: While you were at it, you might as well have suppressed the underlining in section titles ;o)